# How to install ansible-pylibssh using apt instead of pip

Tags: ansible, debian, apt, libssh

I am using WSL2 to run Ansible on Debian 12.2. When I run a playbook that uses SSH to connect I get the following warning message:

`[WARNING]: ansible-pylibssh not installed, falling back to paramiko`

I want to use ansible-pylibssh instead of paramiko and I have to install it via apt instead via pip.

I am unable to find that package.

I have tried using apt, apt-get, aptitude with updated list of packages and I am just not able to find that package to install it.

How can I install it on Debian?

Comment: What is the reason why you don't want to install it with pip?